# extract segment data from array with php

Tags: php, arrays, mobile, extract

i have a exist data similar to in database :
i need extract image address data into array level [pic] to [image] value
i Wants Extract Image address Data From [image] With PHP
I Need Extract Image Address Data For Using Mobile Application  , data recieve on mobile application via JsonArray And Json_encode from php
Thanks Regards For Your Help

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pic] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => file_ext/reporter/images/IMG_20181116_210224_191.jpg
                            [width] => 1280
                            [height] => 960
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => file_ext/reporter/images/IMG_20181116_210250_912.jpg
                            [width] => 1280
                            [height] => 960
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => file_ext/reporter/images/IMG_20181116_210256_141.jpg
                            [width] => 1280
                            [height] => 960
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => file_ext/reporter/images/IMG_20181116_210303_326.jpg
                            [width] => 1280
                            [height] => 960
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => file_ext/reporter/images/IMG_20181116_210310_857.jpg
                            [width] => 1280
                            [height] => 960
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [image] => file_ext/reporter/images/IMG_20181116_210345_024.jpg
                            [width] => 1280
                            [height] => 960
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: expected output?

Comment: Yes I Tried But Not Answer that was not what I mind , It does not matter if it will be coded on mobile

Comment: Solved With Rahul Meshram Description <3 So Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to fetch all images data,

```
function array_column_recursive(array $haystack, $needle) {
    $found = [];
    array_walk_recursive($haystack, function($value, $key) use (&$found, $needle) {
        if ($key == $needle)
            $found[] = $value;
    });
    return $found;
}
$data = json_encode(array_column_recusrive($input,'image'));
```

[Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: Very Very Very Thank You Dude<3

Comment: @EtherNet Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.